# How to save multiple sessions in tmux?

Tags: linux, tmux

I use `tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect` to restore a tmux session. Albeit, I can only save one session. Is it possible to save multiple sessions in tmux with this plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit late but it seems like this plugin saves all the sessions you've created. So u can reload it and switch to the one u like with `*prefix* + s` and select the desired session.